# Is there a way to have Eclipse flash its taskbar icon once a time consuming task finishes?

Tags: eclipse

I often minimize Eclipse to read or work on something else for a few minutes while I wait for it to do something (e.g., run a large JUnit test suite, synchronize a huge number of files with a repo, run a long Ant build, etc.).  I have to check back every 30 seconds or so to see if it's finished yet. I would like Eclipse to alert me, preferably by blinking its taskbar icon, after it finishes a time consuming operation. Are there any settings or plugins that can make this happen?

Comment: Do you think the OS provides the API to do such thing? On windows 7 Eclipse's taskbar icon can report the progress of install new software. Basically the platform/swt support it on specific OS, however the plug-ins need adapt to use the capability to report progress.

Answer (score 4):

I believe is you have Mylyn installed, this should be enabled by default for Windows 7.  See [here](http://tasktop.com/blog/eclipse/tasktop-working-with-microsoft-to-improve-eclipse-on-windows-7) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=293228).  Regarding the post-build actions, I do not know of any existing Eclipse plugins that do this.  However, I have not exhaustively searched [the marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org).  However, this could be accomplished with existing Eclipse APIs but it would require someone to author a new Eclipse plugin.

The [Eclipse Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/platform/) jobs framework has [an API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/IJobManager.html) called `IJobManager`.  A developer could write a new Eclipse plugin that could use this API to listen for job changes and do the following:

1. Create an eclipse plugin, register a listener to `IJobManager` on startup.
2. Once any interesting job is completed, it could fire off some external task/script using normal java process execution API in the JDK

This all could be accomplished in one Java file, probably less than 500 lines long.
You could use [this template](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Minerva) to setup a basic Eclipse plugin project including [build system](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) and have it built and ready to install into your existing Eclipse.

**Update** I just found a maven archetype for building eclipse plugins with tycho [here](https://github.com/open-archetypes/tycho-eclipse-plugin-archetype).  It would be my recommendation for someone new to building an eclipse feature/updatesite.

Comment: Are you sure this flashes the taskbar icon?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new plugin project and create this kind of functionality for yourself. The 
[IJobchangeListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/IJobChangeListener.html) from the [Eclipse Jobs API](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Concurrency/jobs-api.html) is probably very interesting for you.

The `IJobChangeListener` is an interface where you can receive notifications for the different type of job states.

I have created a class called `JobListener` which adds the `IJobchangeListener` to the `JobManager`. With the action `SampleAction` you can register or unregister the listener. that means, if the listener is registered and your application is minimized you will be notified with a `MessageDialog` (no blinking taskbar).

I found a [link](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/08/swing.html) where someone made his swing application blink. This functionality should be included in the method `public void done(final IJobChangeEvent event)`. I haven't done this in my test class.

You can also get additional information about the [Job](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/Job.html) with

```
event.getJob();
```

Here you are able to check the Job name:

```
String jobName = event.getJob().getName();
```

The name of the Job is human readable, for example "Collecting garbage", "Update for Decoration Completion", "Building workspace", etc.

The `JobListener` class.

```
/**
 * A job listener which may be added to a job manager
 */
public class JobListener {

    private MyJobListener listener = null;
    private IWorkbenchWindow window = null;
    private boolean active = false;

    public JobListener(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    /**
     * register the job listener
     */
    public void register() {
        listener = new MyJobListener(window);

        IJobManager jobMan = Job.getJobManager();
        jobMan.addJobChangeListener(listener);

        active = true;
    }

    /**
     * unregister the job listener
     */
    public void unregister() {
        IJobManager jobMan = Job.getJobManager();
        jobMan.removeJobChangeListener(listener);

        active = false;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    class MyJobListener implements IJobChangeListener {

        private IWorkbenchWindow window;

        public MyJobListener(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
            this.window = window;
        }

        @Override
        public void sleeping(IJobChangeEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void scheduled(IJobChangeEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void running(IJobChangeEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void done(final IJobChangeEvent event) {

            window.getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(window.getShell().getMinimized()) {
                        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                                window.getShell(),
                                "Test",
                                "Job " + event.getJob().getName() + " done.");
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void awake(IJobChangeEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void aboutToRun(IJobChangeEvent event) {
            System.out.println("About to run: " + event.getJob().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I called this class from a class called `SampleAction.java`

```
public class SampleAction implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {
    private IWorkbenchWindow window;
    private JobListener listener;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     */
    public SampleAction() {
    }

    public void run(IAction action) {   
        if(listener.isActive()) {
            listener.unregister();

            MessageDialog.openInformation(
                    window.getShell(),
                    "Lrt",
                    "Unregistered");

        }
        else {
            listener.register();

            MessageDialog.openInformation(
                    window.getShell(),
                    "Lrt",
                    "Registered");
        }
    }

    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
    }

    public void dispose() {
    }

    public void init(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
        this.window = window;
        this.listener = new JobListener(window);
    }
```

You can get started with eclipse plugin development by creating a new plugin project:

```
File > New > Project > Plugin Project
```

I used the `Hello World` plugin project template to test the code above.